# Regex to match hyphen between two specific words

Tags: regex

Given the below sample, how would I match each hyphen found between the words "CAST" and "DATETIME"? (`CAST(N'2013-11-26 10:52:47.957' AS DateTime)`)

The pattern occurs multiple times per row.
There could be hyphens anywhere else in the string that must not be matched.

```
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Content] ([Template], [CreatedDate], [Url], [PublishedDate]) VALUES (N’gallery-item.aspx', CAST(N'2013-11-26 10:52:47.957' AS DateTime), N'some-url', CAST(N'2013-11-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Content] ([Template], [CreatedDate], [Url], [PublishedDate]) VALUES (N’another-item.aspx', CAST(N'2013-11-26 10:52:47.957' AS DateTime), N'some-other-url', CAST(N'2013-11-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
```

`CAST(.*)DateTime` selects all characters between the first occurrence of "CAST" and the last occurrence of "DATETIME" on each row. there could be other hyphens in this selection that shouldn't be matched.

`-` will match any hyphen in the document.

I guess I need to combine these two patterns somehow but my regex knowledge is non-existent. `CAST(-)DateTime` doesn't work.

What is the correct way to do this?

If platform is important: this will be used to do find-replace in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). If this is not possible, I'm absolutely open to using another text/code editor.

Comment: That depends on what tool/regex library you are using.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, I'm wanting to use this in a find-replace in Visual Studio Code. I'm afraid I have no idea which libray they use in the background

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible, since VSC uses ECMAScript 5  regex.

Comment: _“CAST(.*)DateTime selects all characters between the first occurrence of "CAST" and the last occurrence of "DATETIME" on each row”_ – that’s because regex are “greedy.” So you need to switch to un-greedy mode for the .* part. (I don’t know what “flavor” of regex Visual Studio is using, so you’ll need to go look up yourself how to do that in there.)

Comment: what if hyphen selected around digits..?means like :  https://regex101.com/r/dB2fB3/1

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar that wouldn't be robust enough unfortunately. There are other columns in the real dataset that could contain digits and hyphens.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm in no way tied to to using VSC. I have numerous text/code editors and IDE's if you have a suggestion that would work in anther platform.

Comment: @CBroe `.*?` makes it non-greedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use Notepad++, you may use a regex based on a `\G` operator that helps find consecutive matches after an initial match.

Use

```
(?:\bCAST\b|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!\b(?:DATETIME|CAST)\b)[^-])*\K-
```

and replace with any symbol(s) you want (remember that parentheses must be escaped in NPP replacement patterns). Below, I replaced the `-` with `§`.

*Details*:

- `(?:\bCAST\b|(?!^)\G)` - a whole word `CAST` or the end position of the previous match
- `(?:(?!\b(?:DATETIME|CAST)\b)[^-])*` - a tempered greedy token that matches any char but `-` (see `[^-]`) that does not start a sequence of whole words `DATETIME` or `CAST` (see the negative lookahead `(?!\b(?:DATETIME|CAST)\b)`)
- `\K` - a match reset opeator: all text matched so far is discarded
- `-` - the hyphen we want to match

[image]

Comment: That worked a treat. Thank you. You saved me having to edit 4000+ insert statements.